# Diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$ (Torus ) and $\mathbb{S}_{1}\times \mathbb{S}_{1}$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

This is homework so no answers please.

Consider the quotient map $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$ ,where $(x_{1}y_{1})\sim (x_{2},y_{2})$ iff $x_{1}-x_{2},y_{1}-y_{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$. 
I showed that  $\pi|_{(a,b)\times (c,d)}$, where $b-a,d-c\in (0,1)$, is a coordinate chart for $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$.

The question is to: Find diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$ and $\mathbb{S}_{1}\times \mathbb{S}_{1}$.

Any mistakes or shorcuts:

The most natural map I can think of is $f(x,y):=(e^{i2\pi (x)},e^{i2\pi (y)})$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim\mapsto \mathbb{S}_{1}\times\mathbb{S}_{1}$ .

I showed well-defined (for different elements in the equivalence class), bijectivity and smoothness. Now I want inverse smoothness.

My problem is that its' inverse will be $\pi\circ (arg(e^{i2\pi x}),arg(e^{i2\pi y}))$ ($\pi$ was included so that it will map into $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim$)

and so the $(arg(e^{i2\pi x}),arg(e^{i2\pi y}))$ cannot be defined on all of $\mathbb{S}_{1}\times \mathbb{S}_{1}$.

Comment: Are you aware that $\mathbb{S}_{1}$ = $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Well yes, that is the idea behind choosing f; $e^{2\pi i x}$ will not differentiate integer translates.

Comment: I am essentially proving $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\sim $  $\simeq \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Let $\pi'$ be the quotient map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Then it's enough to show that $\pi = \pi'\times\pi'$; but this is essentially trivial.

Comment: How do I take derivatives of quotient maps?

Comment: Because I need to show smoothness of it's inverse. One good way is using IFT.

Comment: Also, this map is not injective

Comment: If $\pi = \pi'\times\pi'$ then $(\mathbb{R}^2/\sim) = \pi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\mathbb{S}_1\times\mathbb{S}_1 = \pi'(\mathbb{R})\times\pi'(\mathbb{R}) = \pi'\times\pi'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ are not merely diffeomorphic, they are actually equal. If you prefer, the desired diffeomorphism is simply the identity map.

Comment: I suppose I have to show that $\mathbb{S}_{1}$ has the same smooth structure with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: or show why they are diffeomorphic. I am not assuming they are equal.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, the map $[x] \rightarrow e^{2\pi ix}$ does the job.